# Pandas get a value from one table based on date range in another table

Tags: pandas

I need to extract the value using the effective date from one table, based on the data range in another table.  The most recent effective date within a range should be the new rate used.

```
df1:
ID          EffectiveDate    Benefit   OldRate    NewRate
45jk9548      03/01/2017       Dental       0         15
45jk9548      01/01/2018       Dental      15         17
45jk9548      01/25/2018       Dental      17         50


df2:
ID        Benefit    FromDate     ToDate   
45jk9548   Dental   12/25/2017  01/02/2018       
45jk9548   Dental   01/08/2018  01/15/2018     
45jk9548   Dental   01/15/2018  01/22/2018
45jk9548   Dental   01/22/2018  01/29/2018
45jk9548   Dental   01/29/2018  02/05/2018
```

Ideally extracting data from df1 or merging the tables would result in :

```
ID        Benefit    FromDate     ToDate    EffectiveDate    Rate  
45jk9548   Dental   12/25/2017  01/02/2018    01/01/2018       17   
45jk9548   Dental   01/08/2018  01/15/2018    01/01/2018       17    
45jk9548   Dental   01/15/2018  01/22/2018    01/01/2018       17
45jk9548   Dental   01/22/2018  01/29/2018    01/25/2018       50
45jk9548   Dental   01/22/2018  01/29/2018    01/25/2018       50
```

I've tried some nested for loops, but I kept getting the largest/last rate as the rate for all rows.  Thanks and greatly appreciate any input on how to approach this issue.

Comment: For the 2nd row, there is no effective date between from and to date. Why is '01/01/2018' selected?

Comment: The FromDate is actually not relevant - I think the more important comparison would be effective date vs To Date.  The effective date would need be the most recent effective date that is not greater than the ToDate - so any To Date that is less than 01/25/2018 would get the 01/01/2018 effective date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can first locate the row of correct EffectiveDate and Rate, then merge them with df2.

```
(
    df2.ToDate
    .apply(lambda x: df1.loc[df1.EffectiveDate.le(x)]
                     .sort_values('EffectiveDate')
                     [['EffectiveDate','NewRate']]
                     .iloc[-1]).apply(pd.Series)
                     .set_axis(['EffectiveDate', 'Rate'], axis=1, inplace=False)
    .pipe(lambda x: pd.concat([df2,x], axis=1))
)

Out[285]: 
         ID Benefit   FromDate     ToDate EffectiveDate  Rate
0  45jk9548  Dental 2017-12-25 2018-01-02    2018-01-01    17
1  45jk9548  Dental 2018-01-08 2018-01-15    2018-01-01    17
2  45jk9548  Dental 2018-01-15 2018-01-22    2018-01-01    17
3  45jk9548  Dental 2018-01-22 2018-01-29    2018-01-25    50
4  45jk9548  Dental 2018-01-29 2018-02-05    2018-01-25    50
```

Comment: Wow, that impressive piece of code - thanks so much, this is really helpful.